# getting an error when trying to load ODBC on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, odbc

$ npm install odbc

> odbc@2.2.2 install /home/user/project/node_modules/odbc
>   node-gyp configure build

gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:167:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-29-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/user.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/bin/node" "/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/GASC-RET/node_modules/odbc
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! odbc@2.2.2 install: `node-gyp configure build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the odbc@2.2.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2020-05-07T22_19_29_684Z-debug.log

****I ensured below command is executed first, although when I type unixodbc -v I don't get anything back..****

~$ sudo apt install unixodbc unixodbc-dev
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
unixodbc-dev is already the newest version (2.3.6-0.1build1).
unixodbc is already the newest version (2.3.6-0.1build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.

***this is my first time configuring Ubuntu for my app and I'm sure I'm missing steps, but can't find a proper step by step online to follow*****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I was missing Ubuntu-make (below snipped is from official site, explaining what "make" does.  I was able to install it via sudo apt install build-essential; which installs "make" among other packages. I could have also gone with sudo apt install make.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make

Ubuntu Make is a command line tool which allows you to download the latest version of popular developer tools on your installation, installing it alongside all of the required dependencies (which will only ask for root access if you don't have all the required dependencies installed already), enable multi-arch on your system if you are on a 64 bit machine, integrate it with the Unity launcher. Basically, one command to get your system ready to develop with!